# How do I redirect to my form after a Laravel failed form validation

Tags: laravel-5

When there is a failed validation , my form page was redirected to 'localhost' which is the php info page instead of form page to be displayed again. I don't know what's wrong﻿. P. S I'm working with laravel 5.2.35

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return redirect()->back()->with('failAuth', true);
```

At the page where your form is, you can add this line

```
   <script>
    var failAuth = "{{Session:has('failAuth')}}";
    if (failAuth)
    {
      alert("Authentication failed. Please resubmit your form"); //or whatever code you wanna execute
    }
   </script>
```

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to achieve this:
You can refer to this at [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('your_form_url')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput($input_variable);//optional
        }
```

You can then display these errors by referencing $errors variable in your view.

> Note: The $errors variable is bound to the view by the Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group. When this middleware is applied an $errors variable will always be available in your views, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used.